# Консольная графика c++ независимая от платформы

Tags: c++, графика, ncurses

Подскажите пожалуйста библиотеку для работы с консолью для c++, типа ncurses.h или windows.h только независимую от платформы (может быть на основе предыдущих).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так ncurses как раз и кроссплатформенен, его и используйте.